# Test for empty string

Tags: conditionals

I have this code to see if `member_order_comments` is blank or not.

```
{if '{member_order_comments}' != ''}
```

It works fine, unless there is a `'` in the middle of `member_order_comments`, in which case I get a php error. I understand why the php error. I don't know the right way to check for an empty string when the string can have any format.

Comment: Is this a custom add-on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe if you use:

```
{If your_field} something exists {/if}
```

This should display conditional content if the field contains anything at all.